# PHP: Function parameter weirdness I can't find a rule for

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a class with a static function:

```
public static function log($logEntryType) 
{
...
{
```

in the same class I have a few CONSTS:

```
const TEST1 = 'test1';
const TEST2 = 'test2';
```

From another class I am making the following call;

```
MyLogClass::log(MyLogClass::TEST1);
```

For some reason in PHPStorm 8 -- the whole line is marked with a `Expected \App\Log but got string`.

Isn't what I'm doing legitimate? where is \App\Log coming into the game? Is this something real or some kind of IDE cancer?

Comment: Did it work ? or not?

Comment: Do you have multiple classes in different namespaces called `MyLogClass`?  I've seen this mess up IDEs before.

Comment: It did, but this complaint about an unexpected parameter drives me crazy

Comment: 1) Try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE 2) Where IDE takes you to if you Ctrl+Click on `log` in `MyLogClass::log(MyLogClass::TEST1);` ? 3) Show screenshot of what IDE thinks about that call (Ctrl+Q or `View | Quick Documentation` on `log` in that line)

Comment: I guess clearing the cache worked. If you provide this as an answer I'll credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer worked for me:

1. Go to File → Invalidate Caches... and restart the IDE.
2. Check where the IDE takes you to if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on `log` in `MyLogClass::log(MyLogClass::TEST1);`.
3. Show a screenshot of what the IDE thinks about that call (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or View → Quick Documentation on `log` in that line).